# Center Unordered Lists In DIV

Tags: css, list, center, unordered

Well I'm in the mix of redesigning my website AlternativeApps.TK so the user gets the best experience.

I have a div called devices which has images of the Windows icon, Linux, Mac, Android, and iOS devices. Under the devices are their names. the text is centered under their icons, but I can't seem to figure out how to center all the images, and text in the same div horizontally, not going down vertically like it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit for new information about horizontal layout:

```
#devices > ul {display: inline-block;}
```

There! That's all you need to add. No nasty brittle floats.

Comment: What's > do? I never learned about that, or heard of inline-block.

Comment: `inline-block` changes how elements are supposed to be displayed, and `>` is used as a descendant selector. so only `ul`s which are children of #devices will be styled.

Comment: You don't actually need it in this example; it's just a habit because it's a bit quicker in browsers. It selects direct descendants, so `#devices ul` picks out all uls under #devices, whereas `#devices > ul` picks out the ones that are its direct children. It's so common to have nested uls for submenus that I just put in out of habit. It's fairly common though. On the other hand, inline-block is good standard CSS2, but for some strange reason isn't so common. A lot of people have a weird dislike of it. It makes something block on the inside, and inline on the outside. Very convenient here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I misunderstood the question initially try this instead.

```
#devices{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px /* arbitrary value to stop them from hitting eachother */
    text-align : center;
}
```

Then change your markup to something like

```
<div id="devices">
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <img src="your image"/>
            <p>your text</p>
        </li>
        <li> ... so on</li>
        <li> ... so on</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thanks, that worked, how can I get all of the images, and such in the middle of the div, and not going down vertically?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood your question I guess... you want them all horizontal.

Comment: @mikethedj4 alright the above *should* be what your looking for.

Comment: I would suggest not using floats; if you're going to add other stuff to the page they can cause problems. Slightly simpler to use `inline-block` (see my answer).

Comment: Yeah I want them centered horizontally, but not going down vertically. All in the same div, with the text displaying below the images like I have them.

Comment: eh `inline` is a good solution as well, but as long as you use `float` properly theres no issues.

Comment: True; nothing wrong with float if you need it, but I've spent too much of my life debugging browser issues to run straight to it. You beat me to the answer with it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#devices ul { display:block; float:left; }
```